# ParametricPlot Options Problem: PlotStyle and AxisLabel issues

Tags: plotting, options

I am plotting the best response functions in a basic quantity setting Duopoly model using the `ParametricPlot` function. The issue is that the resulting graphs are both "black" even thought I have specified the `PlotStyle -> {{Blue,Thick},{Red,Thick}}`, and the `AxisLabel -> {q1,q2}` option is also not be working. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong here?

```
BRq1[q2_, c1_, a_] := 1/2 (a - c1 - q2);
BRq2[q1_, c2_, a_] := 1/2 (a - c2 - q1);
Manipulate[
ParametricPlot[{{q2, BRq1[q2, c1, a]}, {BRq2[q1, c2, a], q1}}, {q1, 
0, 100}, {q2, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Red, Thick}}, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}}, AxesLabel -> {q1, q2}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
PlotLabel -> Style["Best Response Curves", Blue, 20]], 
Style["Parameters", Bold, Medium], {c1, 0, 50}, {c2, 0, 100}, {a, 10,130}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About `Axis`, for two parameters th default is `Frame` so use `FrameLabels`.

If there are two parameters then MMA expects some kind of surface, this causes confusion. What you see is not the "plot" but the boundary of this expected region. You can fix this with:

```
Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> (EdgeForm /@ Directive @@@ {{Blue, Thick}, {Red, Thick}})
```

[image]

I'd go with one parameter:

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{{q1, BRq1[q1, c1, a]}, {BRq2[q1, c2, a], q1}}, 
                {q1, 0, 100}, PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}, {Red, Thick}}, 
                PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 100}}], 
 {c1, 0, 50}, {c2, 0, 100}, {a, 10, 130}]
```